# Please help with this Bayesian PP problem

Tags: bayesian

Only 1 in 10 persons opt for a middle berth in "sleeper class" of Indian railways. What is the probability of getting a middle berth in sleeper compartment?

In every coupe, there are 2 Middle Berths out of 8 total berths.

Let me try to solve: Simple probability of getting a middle berth is 2/8 = 0.25, but actual probability, I suspect, is very high (as only 1 in 10 opt for it, 9/10 do not opt for it).

$$
P(M \mid D) = \frac{P(D \mid M)\, P(M)}{P(D)}
= \frac{0.25 \times 0.9}{P(D)}
$$

I am stuck up here, what is $P(D)$?

Comment: Will this question be ever approved, @Tim?

Answer (score 0):

By the [law of total probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability)

$$
P(D) = P(D|M)\,P(M) + P(D|\neg M)\,P(\neg M)
$$

Comment: (0.25 x 0.9) / {(0.25 x 0.9) + (0.75 x 0.1)} = 0.75, 75% chance. Is it correct? Thanks  lot Tim